# Why doesn't this selection-sort program in python work correctly?

Tags: python, sorting, selection-sort

I wrote a selection sort implementation that doesn't work. I can't figure out why.

```
#!/usr/bin
def sel_sort(list):
    for i in xrange(n-2):
        imin=i
        for j in xrange(i+1,n-1):
            if list[j]<list[imin]:
                imin=j
        list[imin],list[i]=list[i],list[imin]

n=int(raw_input("Enter number of elements : "))
x=[]
for t in xrange(n):
    x.append(int(raw_input()))

sel_sort(x)

for k in xrange(n):
    print x[k],
```

Also could anyone explain why I should place `#!/usr/bin` at the beginning of this program?

Comment: Can you provide some more details?

Comment: The first line should read `#!/usr/bin/env python`. It's a hashbang, or [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). The algorithm is buggy though

Comment: @slezica This should work though.

Comment: Note: Don't use `list` as a variable name, as it is a Python function.

Comment: got that thanks. @MartinEvans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, after every other iteration the following was the result,

```
[0, 3, 77, 25, 87, 22, 12, 7, 2, 43]
[0, 2, 77, 25, 87, 22, 12, 7, 3, 43]
[0, 2, 3, 25, 87, 22, 12, 7, 77, 43]
[0, 2, 3, 7, 87, 22, 12, 25, 77, 43]
[0, 2, 3, 7, 12, 22, 87, 25, 77, 43]
[0, 2, 3, 7, 12, 22, 87, 25, 77, 43]
[0, 2, 3, 7, 12, 22, 25, 87, 77, 43]
[0, 2, 3, 7, 12, 22, 25, 77, 87, 43]
[0, 2, 3, 7, 12, 22, 25, 77, 87, 43]
0 2 3 7 12 22 25 77 87 43
```

As you can clearly see, it ignores the last element!

xrange basically generates from start to end-1 (xrange(start,end))!

The inner loop should be of range i+1 to n and not n-1

```
def sel_sort(list):
    for i in xrange(n-2):
        imin=i
        #here range is i+1 to n
        for j in xrange(i+1,n):
            if list[j]<list[imin]:
                imin=j
        list[imin],list[i]=list[i],list[imin]
        print list
```

Example,

Input:

```
x=[7, 3, 77, 25, 87, 22, 12, 0, 2, 43]
```

Output:

```
0 2 3 7 12 22 25 43 77 87
```

The use of #!/usr/bin at the beginning of this program can be well understood by wiki link shared in comments. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script) would give a clear insight about the same!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes! Thank You Keerthana, but could you provide details why i+1 to n and not n-1 ?

Comment: because you were ignoring the last element while iterating! I've added the edits! Did that answer you question?

Comment: `xrange(N)` generates numbers from `0` to `N -1` (not `N`). Consequently `xrange(n-2)` provides numbers form `0` to `n-3` etc.